# Can a backup by cbbackup 6.0 be restored by cbrestore 5.1?

Tags: couchbase

Can a cbbackup 6.0 be restored by cbrestore 5.1?  We have XDCR setup between Couchbase 5.1 and 6.0 clusters, and I want to do backups on the 6.0 cluster.  If there is a catastrophic issue, and I need to rebuild everything, I need to know if cbrestore 5.1 will be able to restore the 6.0 backups?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Here is the compatibility matrix https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/backup-restore/enterprise-backup-restore.html#version-compatibility

As they are very close versions, it should work without any major problems.